# Google Calendar Event Notifications are not coming in gmail's of attendees

Tags: reactjs, gmail, google-calendar-api

I am using google calender api for inserting event in google calender & its also adding in attendess google calender but problem is that notification of event creation is not showing in attendees & also in owner account.

I am using react as frontend.

Anykind of help or sharing is most appreciated.

My code:-

```
function addManualEvent(){
    var event = {
      'kind': 'calendar#event',
      'summary': 'Last Event 9',
      'location': 'Masai School, Bangalore',
      'description': 'Paty time',
      'start': {
        'dateTime': '2023-03-17T14:36:00.000Z',
        'timeZone': 'UTC'
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': '2023-03-17T14:37:00.000Z',
        'timeZone': 'UTC'
      },
      'recurrence': [
        'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1'
      ],
      'attendees': [
        {'email': 'sureshsingh11661@gmail.com','responseStatus':'needsAction'},
        {'email': 'ritiksingh11661@gmail.com','responseStatus':'needsAction'}
      ],
      'reminders': {
        'useDefault': true,
      },
      "guestsCanSeeOtherGuests": true,
      'sendUpdates': 'all'
    }
      var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({'calendarId': 'primary','resource': event});
      request.execute(function(event) {
          console.log(event)
          window.open(event.htmlLink)
      },function(error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

I want notification of event in owner & also attendees's gmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding `'sendUpdates': 'all'` as part of your `event` object and it doesn't go there. The `sendUpdates` parameter is part of the *query parameters*. If you check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert) for `events.insert` you'll see that `sendUpdates` is in the parameters section, not in the request body.

To correct this, add `sendUpdates` in your `gapi.client.calendar.events.insert` call. Make sure to also remove it from your `event` variable:

```
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
      "calendarId": "primary",
      "sendUpdates": "all",
      "resource": event
      })
```

##### Reference

- [Events.insert documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)